# Odd Behaviour of breaks_fun Function

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have been dealing with a problem that is like a mystery to me. I can the following plot with the code below:

```
# Custom y-axis breaks ~
breaks_fun <- function(x){
  if (min(x) < 1){
    seq(1, 4)}
  else if (min(x) < 83){
    seq(85, 95, by = 5)}
  else if (min(x) < 100){
    seq(96, 99, by = 1)}
  else { 
    seq(0, 40000000, by = 5000000)}}


# Custom y-axis labels ~
plot_index_labels <- 0
labels_fun <- function(x) {
  plot_index_labels <<- plot_index_labels + 1L
  switch(plot_index_labels,
         scales::label_number(accuracy = 0.1, suffix = "X")(x),
         scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1, scale = 1, big.mark = "")(x),
         scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1, scale = 1, big.mark = "")(x),
         scales::label_number(accuracy = 1, big.mark = "", suffix = "M")(x))}


# Creates the panel ~
BSG_Combined <- 
 ggplot() +
  geom_violin(data = fulldfUp, aes(x = Species, y = Value),
              fill = "#ffffff", colour = "#000000", show.legend = FALSE, alpha = .9, size = .3, width = .7) +
  stat_summary(data = fulldfUp, aes(x = Species, y = Value),  
               fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 21, size = 3.5, alpha = .9, colour = "#000000", fill = "#000000") +
  facet_grid(Category ~. , scales = "free", labeller = labeller(Category = ylabels)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks_fun, labels = labels_fun) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#ffffff"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "#ededed", linetype = "dashed", size = .00005),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(1, "cm"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "#000000", size = .3),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "#000000", size = 16, face = "bold", angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "#000000", size = 16, face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = "#000000", size = .3),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "#000000", size = .3),
        strip.background.y = element_rect(colour = "#000000", fill = "#d6d6d6", size = 0.3),
        strip.text = element_text(colour = "#000000", size = 20, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.margin = margin(t = 0, b = 0, r = 0, l = 0),
        legend.box.margin = margin(t = 10, b = 20, r = 0, l = 0),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA),
        legend.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

So, as you can see the `breanks_fun` function works for all the facets but for the last one. I have tried to change the function in countless ways -- including adding a final `else if` [e.g. `(min(x) > 1000)`] but no combination works. I can also do it without the `labels = labels_fun` function and the result is the same. I have managed to use this very same function on another data, but it seems that something is going off when I try to apply it on this new data.

Some info:

```
> summary(TotalReads$Value)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
  576504  6209678 10267860 10715209 14395940 34754853
```

So the only difference between this data and my previous data is that here the discrepancy between the min and max values is bigger. However, I do not see how this could affect the `breanks_fun` function since these samples are so different from the ones present in the other 3 categories, hence the else should be more than enough anyway.

Would anyone be able to spot something that I have been missing?
I would very much appreciate any help.

Best regards, George.

Comment: It would be eaiser to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. Also, as your theme adjustments are not important for your issue I would suggest to remove them. Makes it easier to focus on the core of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the matter is that `breaks_fun` is passed the limits of the plot, not the data, which are by default expanded. See the `expand` argument in the help for `scale_y_continuous`

> "For position scales, a vector of range expansion constants used to
> add some padding around the data to ensure that they are placed some
> distance away from the axes. Use the convenience function expansion()
> to generate the values for the expand argument. The defaults are to
> expand the scale by 5% on each side for continuous variables, and by
> 0.6 units on each side for discrete variables."

For the last data set, this makes the bottom limit negative. Consequently, the breaks are created at `seq(1,4)`. Add a `print` statement to `breaks_fun` to see this. (I just used your summary data as the data set which did replicate the behavior)

```
smpData <- c(576504,  6209678, 10267860, 10715209, 14395940, 34754853)
smpDf <- data.frame(
  Value = rep(smpData, 5),
  Species = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = length(smpData))
)


breaks_fun <- function(x){
  print(x)
  ....<other code>...

#>[1] -1132413 36463770
```

Seems like you have two options. One, instead of using `min` to set the breaks, use `max`. `breaks_fun` becomes (linted it a bit to my coding style):

```
breaks_fun <- function(x){
  caseVal <- max(x)

  if (caseVal < 1){
    seq(1, 4)
  } else if (caseVal < 83){
    seq(85, 95, by = 5)
  } else if (caseVal < 100){
    seq(96, 99, by = 1)
  } else {
    seq(0, 40000000, by = 5000000)
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the `expand` argument, but you plots will rest on the x-axis.

```
scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = breaks_fun, labels = labels_fun, expand = c(0, 0)
  )
```

You can also combine this with setting the `limits` argument explicitly to give you some spacing, but make sure to also adjust `expand` so that the limits stay positive/satisfy your switch statement in `breaks_fun`.

Comment: Thanks very much, @Marcus! 

I did try to use `expand`, but it did not look super nice as you anticipated. Thus, I changed the `breaks_fun` function as you indicated and now it works! I had no idea that the function was going through the limits and not the data! 
Thanks a lot!

# Custom y-axis breaks ~
breaks_fun <- function(x){
  caseVal <- max(x)
  print(x)
  if (caseVal < 6){
    seq(1, 4, by = 1)}
  else if (caseVal < 99.1){
    seq(96, 99, by = 1)}
  else if (caseVal < 99.3){
    seq(85, 100, by = 5)}
  else { 
    seq(5000000, 35000000, by = 10000000)}}